# Create a temporary file from a stdout redirect or pipe

Tags: shell, io-redirection, pipe

Some commands only output to stdout.
Some tools only work on files.
Is there a command that can glue those together?

Contrived simple example:

> `diff $(echo 1 | stdout-to-temp-file) $(echo 2 | stdout-to-temp-file)`

My actual use case; Current workaround:

> `git show HEAD:$1 > /tmp/left && meld /tmp/left $1`

My actual use case; Desired:

> `meld $(git show HEAD:$1 | stdout-to-temp-file) $1`

I'd use this in a few other situations too (i.e. I'm not looking for a git or meld only fix).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use `<` to redirect your output to `stdin`.

I don't know how `meld` works, but about your diff example, here's how it would work:

**Using tempfiles**

```
$ cmd1 > file1.tmp
$ cmd2 > file2.tmp
$ diff file1.tmp file2.tmp
```

**Without tempfiles**

```
$ diff <(cmd1) <(cmd2)
```

Note that syntax may vary a bit according to the shell you're using (I'm using ksh88).

Comment: +1, but that's not redirection. It is [Process Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#PROCESS-SUB) ... Process substitution uses /dev/fd/<n> ... eg `gedit <(echo Hello)` will open a file named `63` or some such `fd` number, and the "Hello", which was sent to stdout, simply vanishes into the bit-bucket of that process, because `gedit` doesn't accept stdin, eg `echo Hello | gedit`.

Comment: Process substitution isn't POSIX standard, and isn't available on every shell out there, so be aware of that if you're using it in a script.

Answer (score 10):

[`mktemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp) will create a temporary filename for you. Save the filename in a variable, and use that in both slots.

For a better solution for your precise problem, check out [`git difftool`](http://man.he.net/man1/git-difftool). I have mine setup to use meld, and it's pretty great.

Comment: This is the right way to go - much better than using a fixed file name.

Comment: +1 for both `mktemp` and difftool. An alternative to `mktemp` is `tempfile` or a file name composed using `$$` variable (less secure).

Answer (score 3):

I've never used meld but you can accomplish this typically using the - argument to most cli utilities. e.g.

```
cat /path/to/left/file | diff /input/from/right/file -
```

Specifically for your meld command you might try something like:

```
git show HEAD:$1 | meld - $1
```

Comment: oops initial diff command was incorrect